# How to perform an automatic login for only a certain route in Symfony 3.3?

Tags: symfony, authentication, routes

I know that this is not the best practice to perform a question, but I really can't find anything nowhere!
I have a huge complex Symfony 3.3 application that works based on authentication via FOS User Bundle. I have a single twig template, rendered by a specific route that I need to show even if the user is not logged in.
Is there a way to perform this thing? If so, how? Is there a support page on Sensio website or somewhere where I can find a tutorial or an explanation?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure that the route(url) is not listed in app/confing/security.yml file under security:access_control or allow access to the needed path by adding role to it "IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY ". Also check whether there is no voter called in the controller action.

Comment: THANK YOU, you saved me!